# django-compressor is not install with django-shop

Tags: python, django

I cann't install django-compressor with django-shop. It's give an error like this.

```
Failed building wheel for rcssmin
=================================

Failed building wheel for rjsmin
------------------------------------------------------------------

Command "/home/raisul/Django/Django-Shop/virenv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-_3410eu4/rcssmin/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-kau2lsqm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/raisul/Django/Django-Shop/virenv/include/site/python3.5/rcssmin" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_3410eu4/rcssmin/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 15):

Running these commands solved the problem for me:

```
pip install rcssmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install rjsmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install django-compressor --upgrade
```

Comment: rjsmin kept failing saying that "--without-c-extensions" was not recognized. But `pip install rjsmin==1.0.12 --install-option="--without-c-extensions"` worked.

Comment: Nice one, helps a lot, +1

Comment: i try in django 3.2 it doesnt work, any idea ?

Comment: @EkoBayu No idea. Perhaps some commands need to be tweaked or the issue is something else entirely.

Comment: finally i try to make it on 1 line code like this one and works for me => pip install rcssmin rjsmin django-compressor install-option="--without-c-extensions"